# Is Pubmed returning invalid XML results?

Tags: java, xml, ncbi, pubmed

I am using [JEUtils](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jeutils/) to fetch and parse Pubmed results in Java (it's a tool which seems to be abandoned).

Since a few days ago the tool is throwing exceptions in some results, and upon inspection it seems that Pubmed is not respecting its own [DTD](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/databases/dtd/nlmmedlinecitationset_160101.dtd) (the first one in [its DTDs Page](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/databases/dtd/index.html)).

For example, [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24714850), whose XML result you can see by Format: XML or see [directly here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mmalmeida/b1fb8ab31ee202db9fb426b0aa159c21/raw/d74caf24afbab9fc8a35abae476dec14b50d7ae9/gistfile1.txt) has the following elements:

```
 <DataBankList CompleteYN="Y" />
 <GrantList CompleteYN="Y" />
```

But according to the DTD these elements must have at least one nested element:

```
<!ELEMENT   DataBankList (DataBank+)>
<!ELEMENT   GrantList (Grant+)>
```

**Question: am I missing something, or is Pubmed creating result XMLs which do not comply with their own DTD?**

Comment: @kjhughes that is true. I am not referring to the attribute CompleteYN. I am referring to the fact that DataBankList and GrantList are empty (ie, they don't have any sub-elements) while apparently from the DTD they need at least one DataBank and one GrantList, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you're right. The 2016-01-01 NLMMedlineCitationSet DTD seems to be the most recent version (see also https://www.nlm.nih.gov/databases/dtd/history_dtd_nlmmedline.html), and it does seem to demand one or more child elements for these two elements.

I would use the "Contact NLM" link at https://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/licensee/elements_descriptions.html to open a support ticket.

Comment: Sure looks like it. I've sent them a question yesterday and they "sent it to their development team". Let's see what they answer.

Comment: I accepted this answer after receiving official acknowledgement from Pubmed of the issue.